# Angular 7 Singleton Service To Communicate between two components

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular7

I have two components and a service. I want to use the service to store a common value. `StripeComponent` sets the value in the service. I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'setAddress' of undefined

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'

import { Address } from '../_models/address'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ConfigService } from '../_services/config.service';

declare var Stripe;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stripe',
  templateUrl: './stripe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stripe.component.css'],
  providers: [ConfigService]
})
export class StripeComponent implements OnInit {
  public address = 
    new Address(
  {
    name:"",
    address_city: "",
    address_line1: "",
    address_line2: "",
    address_state: "",
    address_zip: "",
    address_country: ""
  }
)
configService: ConfigService 

  constructor() {         
   }

  ngOnInit(){
  // create observable address$
    this.address$.subscribe( (address: Address) => { 
    console.log(address); }) ;

      this.configService.setAddress(this.address); <-- error here

  } 

}
```

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Address }from '../_models/address';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  constructor() { }

  private config : Address;
  // set the address from stripe component
    setAddress(value) {
      this.config = value;
    }

  public getAddress() {
          return this.config;
  }
```

}

Comment: The value of `configService` isnt setted anywhere, so it defaults to undefined. If you want angular to provide it, you will have to use constructor injection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to inject `ConfigService` to the constructor of `StripeComponent` e.g

```
export class StripeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
}
```

[How to use create and consume services in Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Answer (score 3):

As you declared your **ConfigService** as "injectable" (`@Injectable`) you have to **inject** it in your constructor:

```
constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
```